# Transforming Cursor code to regular SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a piece of cursor code which I am trying to rewrite to a regular SQL code but I am getting an error. Here's the Cursor code:

```
FROM            sr_cursor
INTO            @partyID, @serviceRequestID WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
            SELECT        @customerName = c.TradeName, @legalName = c.LegalName
            FROM            v_RptCompany_v001 c 
            INNER JOIN
                          v_RptAppCompany_v001 ac ON ac.PartyID = c.PartyID AND ac.BeginDate = c.BeginDate
            WHERE        ac.AppID = @gappID AND ac.PartyID = @partyID 
            IF          (@customerName IS NULL OR DATALENGTH(@customerName) = 0) 
BEGIN
SET             @customerName = @legalName 
END
```

My Code:

```
SELECT          C.TradeName as CustomerName, 
            C.LegalName as LegalName, (CASE WHEN CustomerName IS NULL OR DATALENGTH(CustomerName) = 0 THEN CustomerName = LegalName ELSE CustomerName END) AS CustName 
FROM            v_RptCompany_v001 c 
INNER JOIN      v_RptAppCompany_v001 ac 
ON              ac.PartyID = c.PartyID AND ac.BeginDate = c.BeginDate
```

I suspect its the case statement because of which I am getting an error. Please suggest the possible answer. Appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

> Pls note: The AppID is the parameter but I don't want to have any
>   parameter

.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have a 'ELSE' added to your case when for default behaviour.

Comment: It says, incorrct sysntax near '='. Doesn't mention exactly which '=' but I suspect it should be somewhere in Case Statement. I also added ELSE in the statement. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Do you have any NULL field? As per technet : "The DATALENGTH of NULL is NULL." Therefore, null can't be compared to integer.

Comment: I don't really understand what is your goal here, but your error is in this part of the `CASE` expression: `THEN CustomerName = LegalName`. You can't assign a value to a column like that, change it with `THEN LegalName`

Comment: Why do you need to do this? "THEN CustomerName = LegalName". What is your intent? Replace it with THEN LegalName Else CustomerName

Comment: Oh such a silly mistake..Thanks a lot for your quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT          
   C.TradeName as CustomerName, 
   C.LegalName as LegalName, 
   (CASE WHEN CustomerName IS NULL OR DATALENGTH(CustomerName) = 0 
           THEN LegalName 
           ELSE CustomerName END) AS CustName 
FROM            
   v_RptCompany_v001 c 
INNER JOIN      
   v_RptAppCompany_v001 ac ON ac.PartyID = c.PartyID AND ac.BeginDate = c.BeginDate
```